# Word document from web page is downloading incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, ms-word

I need to generate some data on the fly (when a user clicks a button on an .aspx page) and send it to the browser as a Word document.

I found [this article](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article9.aspx) and copied the code. At first it worked perfectly. I made some mods to the code to get it to do what I want and suddenly I found that when IE displayed the box in which it says 'Do you want to open or save MsWordSample.doc(3.77k) from localhost' - when I click 'Open' - it shows initially '100% downloaded' but this disappears (very quickly - you barely get to read it) and is replaced by text that says 'MsWordSample.doc couldn't be downloaded'. If I click 'Retry' it opens Word but it displays a representation of the .aspx page. I.e. it shows the text box and label - it doesn't show the html which is in the Response.Write at the end of the code.

How can this happen? First off it worked fine. I have changed the page back to exactly in the sample code - but it still won't send the right data to Word - it, (after the messing around described above) opens the code on the .aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like `Response.flush()` and `Response.End()` at the end of your code.

Comment: Thank you - brain dead here I am afraid. Haven't sent a document to a browser using Response.Write for years!